# How to allow MAC Address to Access Another network / subnet using IPTABLES?

Tags: networking, iptables, subnet

Its possible to have the MAC to allow Access Another network / subnet?

Im trying using Mac source and FORWARD but not working .

They are on two different networks that are locked to access but only one MAC can access another subnet and this command is not working.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.5.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -m mac --mac-source xx: xx: xx: xx -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.5.0/24 -m mac --mac-source xx: xx: xx: xx -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Unclear. Does you need to route only the packets from one node with some MAC and to deny for all another nodes packets?

Comment: They are on two different networks that are locked to access but only one MAC can access another subnet and this command is not working.

iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.5.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -m mac --mac-source xx: xx: xx: xx -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.5.0/24 -m mac --mac-source xx: xx: xx: xx -j ACCEPT

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not working?  You've told it to allow packets coming in from that one MAC to be forwarded, but any replies from the other network won't be coming in from the same MAC, so they'll presumably get dropped...